# How to use "dump" neo4j shell command in java

Tags: java, shell, neo4j

I'm working on a Java EE application using Neo4j as database. In this application, i need to do some backup of users's projects to compare them in time (for example, a user has a project (Master nodes + children Nodes + Labels + relationships) A, created 01/01/2014, he creates a copy of this project 01/30/2014 and wants to compare it with actual version 1 month later). My idea is to use "dump" from neo4j-shell to copy all of the project when the user wants it, and keep it in the database to make the user able to compare them.

But the problem is there, i'm searching on the internet since 4 days and i'm always stuck with this.

I tried to do it with cypher but the best way for me is neo4j-shell because dump command can return a cypher query to create the same node with labels, relationships and child nodes, then i just have to edit some parameters in it... et voila !

What i need :

- Use neo4j-shell in my application code to use dump command(Java EE)
- be able to get result of dump neo4j-shell command

I don't need to know how to use cypher, i already do it in all of my application, the only reason why i need neo4j-shell in my java code is because i didn't find a way to do something like the backup command in a cypher query (if you know how, please tell me, it should be realy easier to do it with cypher)

I hope you will be able to help me, have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider using the [Neo4J JDBC driver](http://www.neo4j.org/develop/tools/jdbc) to expose the neo4j database as a JDBC connection, and then use other existing tools to query/backup from that JDBC connection.

It seems that as you've found, dump is good for creating cypher that you can use to re-create another neo4j database.  If that isn't what you want, maybe you want to dump the information as tabular data?  Setting up neo4j as a JDBC connection point has the advantage that you can reuse any tool that knows how to talk to a JDBC database, and use all of those to query/format/dump your data.

Comment: Seems like JDBC driver uses Cypher for queries, i can't use dump in cypher because the only shell command i can use are HTTP ones (GET, POST, PUT). But thx for reply, i'll check if there's something to do with it.

Comment: Are you talking about using the RESTful API over HTTP (GET POST PUT)?  If so, you can use the RESTful API to execute cypher queries, but I'm thinking now I don't understand what you mean...

Comment: yes that's the only thing i can do atm with restAPI, but i need something else to use the dump command, RESTful API isn't what i'm looking for, i'm already using it for all of my database queries but i need to use neo4j-shell from java to get a cypher query to copy what i need.

Comment: If you can actually use the neo4j-shell to run cypher, I don't see why you can't use the JDBC wrapper.

Comment: Actually i don't know if i can use JDBC driver to use dump because i didn't tried yet. but the problem is i don't know how to use neo4j-shell in java, it's the only thing i need, i don't need cypher here.

Comment: Using the shell is easy - if you have the db files in the directory foo, you just start it with neo4j-shell -path foo

Comment: I don't think you understand my question ^^ I want to do it in a Java Application, not in bash script :)

Comment: I think you're right.  I don't understand your question.  I recommend going back, editing your question, clarifying it a lot, and adding what your requirements/parameters are (you want to do it in java, not with cypher).  If you want to do it in java, why do you want to use neo4j-shell?  This requires a lot of clarification.

Comment: Done, i hope it's better for you, and for the others (so, in fact, better for me =D)

Answer (score 0):

Just call the [transactional http endpoint](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/rest-api-transactional.html) and use the returned JSON string as comparison.

The example is in the documentation too.

For Java you can look here: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/server-java-rest-client-example.html#_sending_cypher

Comment: Is this solutions making me able to use dump neo4j-shell command? seems like you can only use GET PUT POST with transactional http endpoint